# Spring MessageSource not getting message from properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I did some googling around and found my problem have appeared many times but i have tried all suggested solutions but it is still not working for me

I am keep getting this exception:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'error.null.firstname' for locale 'en'.
```

here is my setup
in my dispatcher-servlet.xml file i have:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value = "error"/>
</bean>
```

i have a properties file (error_en.properties) under src/main/resources/ directly
and it does contain the following line:

```
error.null.firstname=Firstname cannot be null
```

in my code i am trying:

```
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;
    ...
    System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage("error.null.firstname", null, Locale.ENGLISH));
```

but above is not working and is giving me exception mentioned above

I've tried prefixing "classpath:" to 'value' in value attribute but that didn't work for me.
I've ensured that the filename 'error' matches with the value attribute because i know '_en' would be dealt with by Spring Framework.

I can't see what am i missing?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Also, please make sure the name of the property file is correct.

Comment: Eclipse. my property file is "error_en.properties" where i have value attribute to "error" and in code i'm using Locale.ENGLISH in the getMessage method of MessageSource

Comment: Actually I tried same in my eclipse and it's working fine. Can you also make sure `src/main/resources/ ` is in build path?

Comment: yep it is on the build path

Comment: hmm. Not sure what else can be done. Would it be possible to share your eclipse screenshot. Might able to spot something otherwise I tried your code and it's working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after days of experimenting/debugging - finally figured out what the problem is.

The class where i'm autowiring the MessageSource was actually belong to a different context.

My messageSource bean definition was declared in my dispatcher-Servlet.xml context file because i'm developing a web application.

Whereas my business class was declared in application-context.xml so it couldn't find the MessageSource.

After i've moved everything into the dispatcher-Servlet.xml file it work. Probably not an elegant solution but that solved my problem.

Thanks for all help previously